# Include external function into a phpunittest with selenium

Tags: selenium, include, phpunit

Hy guys

I´m trying to include a function from a php-file to my phpunittest.

When i do not include it, it works fine. I already tried some different solutions with i found while googleing...

There is no error message, it is not even starting to run the test.

I want something like that:

this should be the included function in mappingfunction.php

```
<?php
  public function mapping(string catname)
  {
    echo ($catname);

  } ?>
```

This should be the PhpUnit-test:

```
<?php

require_once '/mappingfunction.php' ;

class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://www.google.com");
    $this->setHost("localhost");
    $this->setPort(4444);
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {

    mapping('blabla');

  }
}  ?>
```

Why is it not working? What could I do instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works without the slash :)

```
require_once 'mappingfunction.php' ;
```